# I want to flatten convolution features from image to fully connected network but at this stage I want to add some other features

Tags: machine-learning, conv-neural-network

I want to flatten convolution features from image to fully connected network but at this stage I want to add some other features like date and time along with convolution features and then want to flatten to fully connected neural network.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define the additional features (date, and time) as Input layers, and then you can concatenate these to the flattened layer.

Comment: thank you for your answer.  is it possible with keras library ?. can you write example in keras ?

Comment: For example here they have multiple inputs, and later a concatenate layer, for whichever layers they want to. (multiple inputs is the expression you should search for)
https://keras.io/guides/functional_api/#models-with-multiple-inputs-and-outputs